# Start Parsing CSV File On Line "X"

Tags: php, loops, csv

I'm working on a CSV upload that has 35,000 lines of stuff going on and I'm trying to think of a way to start my parsing of the CSV file at line "X". I've been refreshing the page and saving the line I was last on each time so it would fix the timeout issue I was having with browsers. Now, I just need to know how to start my CSV file on that line I left off.

```
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== false) {
    if($i > 2000) { break; }
    //start parsing here
    $i++
}
$_SESSION['lastLine'] = $i;
$_SESSION['filepath'] = $filepath;
//resend headers
```

I save the filepath as a session as well because it's been uploaded to a temporary folder and I can re-access it. So the first time I upload, I go through all 2000 lines perfectly happy. The headers reset and start the process again, but since $_SESSION['lastline'] is now 2001, the code breaks (which is fine). What I need to figure out is how can I start my parsing on line 2001 and break again on 4000. This will continue until all 35,000 lines are done.

I was thinking about setting the break statement before the parsing to say:

```
if($i < $_SESSION['lastLine']) { $i++; }
if($i > $_SESSION['lastLine'] + 2000) { break; }
```

My problem is, doing 35,000 lines of CSV means that the last 10 or so runs will have to do an i++ loop thousands of times before the parsing even begins. I looked around for some ways to just start the CSV file at line "X", which would be my preferred method of doing this, but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: just set into session not only the last line index, but buffer size (2000) and use it in loop as max value of line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ftell()`](https://www.php.net/ftell) to save your position within the file. You can then [`fseek()`](http://php.net/fseek) to that position before restarting your fgetcsv() loop, e.g.

```
while($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    $cur_pos = ftell($handle);
    if ($some_condition) {
          break;
    }
}
.....

fseek($handle, $cur_pos); // jump back to last position
... continue on wards ...
```

Comment: Marked your answer as the best of the few, but unfortunately I used my option (it worked) because I needed a quick and dirty fix within half an hour. Thanks so much for your response, and when I have a second to come back to this client, I will use your idea because I'm sure it's ten times more efficient than mine.

Comment: For others who my read this useful solution:
1) the function is fgetcsv (not fetgetcsv as shown in the first line)
2) the PHP manual warns that "some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB" see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php

Comment: I think it is [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead of `fetgetcsv`.

Comment: @MarcB WC, I am looking for this type solution, can you provide an working example of your code.

Comment: @MarcB  It seems fseek is offsetting characters and not line numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should save the byte offset along with the line number, then `fseek` to that byte offset before you start parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As I found fseek is offsetting characters, instead of lines
I used [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)

Something like this

```
$file = new SplFileObject('your-csv-file.csv');
//this is zero based so need to subtract 1
$file->seek(2); /// Going to line 3
$arr=$file->fgetcsv();
print_r($arr);
```

To iterate the whole CSV from that line number

```
while(!$file->eof())
{
    $row=$file->fgetcsv();
    print_r($row);
}
```

Functions Link:-
[seek](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php) , [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php)